# segmentation faults when process launched in foreground is stopped with Ctrl+C

Tags: c, linux, process, openwrt

I develop program for openWrt platform, when I launch the process with option foreground, the process runs well.

```
/usr/sbin/myprocess -f -b 

(" -f, --foreground        Run in the foreground\n")  
(" -b, --boot              Run with boot event\n")
```

At the end I stop the process with command `Ctrl + C`. This leads to segmentation faults.

In my main program the code used for that is :

```
 void main ()
    {
    ..........
    ..
   bool foreground = false;
    while (1) {
        c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "fb", long_opts, NULL);
        if (c == EOF)
            break;
        switch (c) {
            case 'b':
                start_event |= BOOT;
                break;
            case 'f':
                foreground = true;
                break;
          } 
      }
    pid_t pid, sid;

        if (!foreground) { // *fourground false* 
            pid = fork();
            if (pid < 0)
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            if (pid > 0)
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

            sid = setsid();
            if (sid < 0) {
                D("setsid() returned error\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            char *directory = "/";

            if ((chdir(directory)) < 0) {
                D("chdir() returned error\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

    ..........


    }
```

I wonder if a process launched in foreground mode must be stop with a specific way. How to modify my C code to avoid this segmentation fault ?

Comment: Where does it fault exactly? Have you done any debugging?

Comment: no any debug are provided

Comment: how to debug this seg fault in openWrt platform !

Comment: Check your signal handler for SIG_INT.

Comment: @Marian : I succeed to bloc the SIG_INT (Ctrl+c signal). and no seg fault issue not reproduced

Comment: @Marian : I wonder now, how to stop process with command ! (Ctrl +z) doesn't kill process

Comment: Very probably, you shall not block SIG_INT signal but fix a bug in your SIG_INT handler.

Comment: the code is for when the execution is NOT in foreground.  so useless for debugging when the execution is foreground.

Comment: the lines: if (pid > 0)
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); results in the parent terminating which turns the child process in a zombie. zombie processes pay no attention to signals.

Comment: @user3629249 : yes, I Want to give you more details about the code when the process run well and with Ctrl + c no segmentation fault is reproduced

Answer (score 1):

Compile your program with `-g`, then run your program under `gdb`. If this is on `openwrt` you might need to use remote `gdb`. That will tell you where the segfault is.

You will need to read [this page](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Signals.html) to ensure that you know how to pass your `^C` to the program, i.e. use

```
handle signal int nostop noprint pass
```

before you `run`.

You've given us no debugging information to go on, but I'm guessing you have a problem either in your signal handler for `SIGINT`, or in your exit code (assuming you trap the signal), or in things invoked at `__atexit` or similar. Occasionally memory corruption can cause this too when exit routines try to clean up - try running under `valgrind`.